# Where is tox/pip looking finding the pypi repo urls?

Tags: python, pip, tox

When I build my python project, tox is taking a really long time to set up the environment. I've traced the slowness to the fact that when it's trying to up the environment in .tox, it's trying to access an old pypi repo that my company has since decommissioned in favor of a new one (which works fine). Most stuff I do tries to access this old repo many times (~100), waiting a second or two to timeout on each connection.

I've done everything I can think of to cleanse my machine of links to the old repository, but it's still lingering somewhere. I've tried:

- Uninstalling & re-installing both tox & pip
- Blowing away ~/.pip
- grepping through my project folders for the url of the old repo
- grepping through in /Library/Frameworks/ for the url of the old repo (this is on OSX Yosemite 10.10.5)

No dice on any of them.

Where else should I look? Is there some obscure nook or cranny I haven't thought of? Where does pip look for repos by default if you don't explicitly specify one?

Answer (score 0):

Can it be tox settings? [This](http://tox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config.html#confval-install_command=ARGV) and [this](http://tox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/example/basic.html#using-a-different-default-pypi-url) parameters seem like they could be relevant. If you don't keep your tox files in the same place as the project itself, you could've missed it while grepping.

Answer (score 0):

Found it through some painstaking println debugging & reading through the source on github. It was in ~/Library/Application Support/pip.

For anyone finding this in the future, pip has some [default directories](https://github.com/pypa/pip/blob/9312dd3fe640f0355d9b04fd2105e87c9db330fb/pip/utils/appdirs.py) it looks in.